# Detect if Flash is installed on Android and embed a Flash video in an Activity

Tags: android, flash, android-webview

This is really a two part question.  First, is it possible to detect if Flash is installed on an Android device?  Second, if it is installed, is it possible to display a flash video in an Activity?  I'm thinking you'd have to use a WebView widget within your Activity to display the Flash content instead of something like a VideoView.  Is Flash even supported within the WebView widget or is it only supported by the actual Browser app?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer to both parts of your questions is "yes", with the second part contingent on the first.

(1) Detecting if Flash is installed.

Use the PackageManager to attempt to obtain the Application Info for the Flash Player package. It will throw an exception of such a package doesn't exist.

```
boolean flashInstalled = false;
try {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
  if (ai != null)
    flashInstalled = true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  flashInstalled = false;
}
```

(2) Provided Flash is installed, you can display a Flash video within your Activity by embedding it within a WebView. The Flash plugin provides the same support for a WebView as the native browser.

If your check in Part 1 returns false, best practice would be to hide your WebView and replace it with either an error message explaining the requirement for Flash, or better still, a link to download the Flash plugin from the Android Market.

Comment: If you're going to link to the Market in the absence of Flash, you should probably check to make sure that the Market is installed before doing so, right Reto? ;)

Comment: @Josh, this app is only available via the official market so I'm not too worried about that.  In my opinion an Android device without the official Google apps (gmail, market, maps, calendar, etc...) isn't really worth owning.

Comment: One key point you left out: webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);  You'll spin your wheels for a while trying to get this to work until you find that setting :)

Comment: Be careful that some HTC devices have a different flash player from Adobe whose package is: com.htc.flash. Check for both.

Comment: FlashPlayer 11 is not supported in some devices , so the above link takes you to the flashplayer page but you cant download it. can any body konw how to detect the device compatibility and redirect to proper flash player version?

Comment: FYI... Adobe has officially stopped developing for mobile devices.
Also, Google Play Store doesn't have Adobe Flash Player app anymore...

Comment: I've tried this on my Nexus 4. It tells me it does have Flash installed, but when I try to see a youtube video on a webview (plugins and jscript enabled), I only get to see the preview (the still frame with the play button on it) and when I push the play button the video area turns gray and shows an icon similar to a cinema film roll. Am I doing something wrong here?