# notify user if he dont have flash player in android phone apps is build using phone gap

Tags: android, cordova, flash

i have build my android apps using phone gap in this i wanted to add one more feature when my apps gets install it also check for flash player if flash player is not there ask to install through showing link how can i do this ??

i am new for phone gap

Please help me if possible share code with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User following code

```
boolean flashInstalled = false;
try {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
  if (ai != null)
    flashInstalled = true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  flashInstalled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thats correct thanks for replying...but i need code in html or in javascript because am working using phone gap tats a cross-platform...

Comment: check this http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html It may work

Answer (score 0):

[Detect if Flash is installed on Android and embed a Flash video in an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617138/detect-if-flash-is-installed-on-android-and-embed-a-flash-video-in-an-activity)

from above: It will throw an exception of such a package doesn't exist.

```
boolean flashInstalled = false;
try {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
  if (ai != null)
    flashInstalled = true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  flashInstalled = false;
}
```

as for installing it you could just provide a link to flash on the marketplace.

Comment: Thats correct thanks for replying...but i need code in html or in javascript because am working using phone gap tats a cross-platform...and it uses language html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Am I late here? I have used a simple library [FlashDetect](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html).

And the usage is pretty simple :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flash_detect_min.js"></script>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFlashInstalled = FlashDetect.installed;
</script>
```