# Cannot play video inside WebView using iframe tag?

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I am using the following data to display in a `WebView`. These are the HTML tags along with
the iframe which is referring to a video.

Now the problem is when I click on it, it shows the play button but cannot play the video.

Can I play this video inside `WebView` or not?

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;P&gt; because of Jon’s pro-growth, business-friendly policies,&amp;nbsp;Utah&#039;s economy expanded at more than triple the national rate and was named the best state for business by&amp;nbsp;&lt;EM&gt;Forbes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;BR /&gt;&lt;BR /&gt;&lt;IFRAME height=241 src=&quot;http://player.vimeo.com/video/25349114&quot; frameBorder=0 width=425&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;P&gt;America needs a dose of the same medicine. Today, our nation has the second highest corporate tax rate in the developed world. We have convoluted and confusing regulations. 
&lt;!--break--&gt;&lt;!--break--&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

when I try to run this url in the android browser it opens videoview and plays that file perfectly but why not in iframe?
http://player.vimeo.com/video/25349114

Comment: which method you are using to load this string in webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing is to enable browser plugins.

```
// how to enable the webview plugin changed in API 8
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
} else {
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}
```

Also worth checking [flash player is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617138/detect-if-flash-is-installed-on-android-and-embed-a-flash-video-in-an-activity)

Answer (score 2):

```
WebView wv;
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Use this code to load your video and also update the flashplayer of your device...

Comment: Ye that kinda works, just looks crappy from where I'm watching :)