# Streaming Video From Vimeo to Android

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, vimeo

I am looking for a way to stream my videos from vimeo.com to android phone, their API is only available for Web, I have also tried to embed their player in WebView but that way I can see the thumbnail but video won't play, I am using Android 2.2 and Have Flash Player installed.

Is there way to make embedded players work on android or any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the adv api to play vimeo videos. This is the video url the oembed api uses. I managed to get this rendering and playing in webview.

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/<VIDEO_ID_GOES_HERE>?player_id=player&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1&api=1
```

Also worth checking flash player is [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701133/31751) and [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617138/detect-if-flash-is-installed-on-android-and-embed-a-flash-video-in-an-activity)

Comment: Although how you get it to auto play is beyond me at the moment

Answer (score -1):

No you have to use the advanced api and have the user get authorized ive have been trying to find a way around this but have not

the real url would be something like this
http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?quality=mobile&clip_id=s00000000&time=1318531921&sig=4c8a2fcb3303c5b76112046e84f516f8&type=mobile_site
not
player.vimeo.com/video/0000000

which the sig is passed after your set up the oauth with the advanced api which is your key and secret after authorization